# application crashes while opening notifications in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, badge

my application keep crashing when i try to open notifications by clicking on notification badge..i got the following crash report

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation              0x24d33132 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32c8fc72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x24d385f8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184
3   CoreFoundation                  0x24d364d4 ___forwarding___ + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24c659d4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   Skopic                          0x000f7062 -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] (AppDelegate.m:209)
6   UIKit                           0x285d8c7c -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 1836
7   UIKit                           0x285d06a2 -[UIApplication workspace:didReceiveActions:] + 102
8   FrontBoardServices              0x2b7ccebc __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 12
9   CoreFoundation                  0x24cf9250 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x24cf8514 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
11  CoreFoundation                  0x24cf706e __CFRunLoopRun + 1710
12  CoreFoundation                  0x24c4299c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
13  CoreFoundation                  0x24c427ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
14  GraphicsServices                0x2c3f41a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
15  UIKit                           0x283cd690 UIApplicationMain + 1436
16  Skopic                          0x000f46fc main (main.m:15)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x33237aaa tlv_initializer + 2


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x332fddf0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3337ec92 pthread_kill + 58
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3329c934 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3249bbb8 abort_message + 84
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x324b566a default_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32c8ff0e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x324b2dec std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x324b28b4 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32c8fdba objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x24c42a38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 628
10  CoreFoundation                  0x24c427ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x2c3f41a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
12  UIKit                           0x283cd690 UIApplicationMain + 1436
13  Skopic                          0x000f46fc main (main.m:15)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x33237aac start + 0
```

can someone explain why these crashes keep occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to turn the NSDictionary into another NSDictionary with [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:] ... also NSDictionary can be non-nil but contain 0 key entries (an empty dictionary).

Perhaps you want: NSDictionary *apnsPayload = [userInfo objectForKey: @"alert"]; ?

[See:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]intValue]] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
         [[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem].badgeValue = nil;
        }
        else
        {
        [[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem].badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]intValue]];

Comment: the app crashes due to this code..what correction u think i should make?